# Forms not working in portrait on iPad

Tags: wordpress, forms, ipad, portrait

Am stumped! Have just found a very weird anomaly when viewing with an iPad. My forms work fine on a desktop computer and on the iPad in landscape mode but when in portrait mode the fields and buttons cannot be selected.

This form will not work in portrait mode:

- http://www.alpinenurseries.com.au/trade-applications/

But this one will:

- http://www.alpinenurseries.com.au/jobs/production-manager/

Have no idea what might be causing this!!

Any help sorting this out most appreciated.

R

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding `clear:both` to `#services-widget`, it makes the element drop below floated elements.

Comment: Not quite right but you headed me in the right direction. It needed float:right . Thx